# Make footer not overlap content

Tags: html, css, footer

I have 2 complications here, first is that how do I ensure that the footer does not overlap with the content of my articles. Now it seems to overlap the things above it and I can't seem to make the scrollbar with `overflow: auto;`

Also, how do I make the `<hr>`tag work becuase now it seems to mess up my entire flexbox and it only hovers above the first contact footer detail.

Thanks a lot for all your help!!!

```css
    #footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .contact_footer {
    margin-left: 20%;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contact_footer">
            <hr>
                <h3>Contact</h3>
                <address>
                info
                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="contact_footer">
                <h3>Address</h3>
                <address>   
                info
                </address>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you position anything absolutely, it is removed from the normal layout. If you don't want it to overlap with anything below it, you need to make sure there is nothing below it. This is not a tweak for your footer, but for your content.

Try something like this (selectors must be replaced with yours):

```
#content {
    margin-bottom: 20vh;
}
```

`20vh` are 20% of the height of the screen, which might to be the size of your `footer` (your code doesn't make it clear what element your `footer` is positioned in).

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, for second problem

use pseudo class ':first-child' for only first footer content css and use 'border-top' style property instead of 'hr' tag

```
.contact_footer:first-child address{border-bottom:1px solid black;}
```